Custom train_step() in TensorFlow Keras Model not Printing Values Sequentially
class model_sub(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self,modell):
    super().__init__()
    self.model=modell
    self.i=1

  def compile(self,opt,lloss,**kwargs):
    super().compile(**kwargs)
    self.lloss=lloss
    self.opt=opt

  def train_step(self,data):
    print(self.i)
    self.i+=1
    loss=0.007
    return {"loss":loss}

my_model.fit(train_dataset,epochs=1)

If train_step  is called by fit() for every batch of data, why is not the value being printed from 1 to 4 (my no of batches is 4 ).Also what is the purpose of value in the return statement is it just for printing purposes?

You are experiencing the difference between graph mode and eager mode in tensorflow. When you run your code same way you did above, you are running it in graph mode. And there are many pythonic operations become invalid and require tensorflow operations to replicate them in graph mode. But if you run your code in eager mode, then you may able to run pythonic operations (AFAIK, unless there are some unknown surprise!).
To run your code in eager mode and be able to see increasing value of self.i, you can simply pass
my_model.compile(
    opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
    lloss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
    run_eagerly=True
)

But if you run your code in graph mode, you can do as follows and that will not require to set run_eagerly during compilation. Here, you initialize the target variable and increment it by calling tf.assign_add operations to it.
class model_sub(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, modell):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = modell
        self.i = tf.Variable(
            1, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False
        )
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        tf.print(self.i)
        self.i.assign_add(1)
        loss = 0.007
        return {"loss": loss}

